# Changing the direction of the Cycle Carousel

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I want to change direction of .cycle carousel from **right to left** to **left to right**?

```
$zillaSlider2.cycle({
            fx:      'carousel',
            allowWrap: true,
            autoHeight: 0,
            slides: '> li',
            timeout:10,
            speed:  2000,

            updateView: 1, // fire update view one time

        })
```

Could anyone please help me on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there anyone who can provide the solution for this??

Answer (score 0):

If you update to the latest Jquery.Cycle2 then you can use the "reverse" parameter
http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/api/